# Grouping matrix in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am new to Power BI and I have a very basic problem with a matrix object. I was following a tutorial to create a table where my rows are months, my columns are years and the value is the Revenue. However, when I drop the columns the matrix does not show the details by year/month, but automatically summarize al data.

Matrix totals:
[image: Matrix totals]

Can some one tell me is there is any property that I need to change to show all matrix data?

Matrix all  data:
[image: Matrix all data]

Relationships:
[image: Relationships]

Comment: Do you have properly connected tables in your datamodel? This might be caused by a missing relationship

Comment: @GiovanniLuisotto, I think so,I edit my post with the relationships.

Comment: that does not add any information, you need to check the columns included in the relationship (hopefully "Date"). If the column Date is used in the relationship then ensure the values match (just put "date" from table A and B in the same table visual)

Comment: Click on the down arrow from the Columns(Year) column and select don't summarize, repeat the same for revenue as well.

Comment: @GiovanniLuisotto, the relationship was correct, by Date field. The problem was that in bi_salesFact table the 'Date' field was stored as Text,  while in Date table 'Date' field was stored as Date. When changing the Text format to Date works fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @balaji thanks for your tip too. I tried, but the problem was with the format of one of the fields.

Comment: @balaji Good point for year column. However, revenue should be summarized.

Comment: I've added the suggestions as an answer in order to better track it (for the guys who will have similar problems in the future)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be caused by a missing or not working relationship.

Check the columns included in the relationship (hopefully "Date"). If the column Date is used in the relationship then ensure the values match (just put "date" from table A and B in the same table visual).

As you have discovered, the data type of the two columns must match in order for the relationship to work